# Creating invoice template with split voucher/invoice lines

Tags: ms-word

I am using merge fields to merge the data onto the word template.

My template has three sections
1. Check stock
2. Invoice Lines
3. Invoice Lines

So in a single page, invoice lines will be printed twice
Invoice Lines fields are specified in a table. So when the merge happens, there might be x number of rows added to both the tables.

What needs to happen:
If there are 20 rows, and each table can fit 10  rows, then first page will print 10 invoice lines on both tables and a second page will be added to print the rest. I am expecting the table rows to break after certain number of lines

What is happening:
the first table prints fully in the first page. second page prints the second table instead of doing hte split

What I have tried:
I created a table with three rows with fixed row heights. 
Row 1: check Stock
Row 2: Invoice Line table
Row 3: Invoice line table

When there are more rows then it doesn't break the inner (invoice line) table to the next page.

Initial layout:

After adding more rows: the outer table doesn't break to next page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3FY0.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6L1K.png

Any ideas ?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).